# Strange python print behavior with unicode

Tags: python, macos, unicode

I am wondering why i can use print to print a unicode string in my OSX Terminal.app, but if i redirect stdout to a file or pipe it to 'more', i get an UnicodeEncodeError.
How does python decides whether it prints unicode or throws an exception.

Comment: Can you please give a short example script that shows the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your terminal encoding is set correctly and when you redirect to a file (or pipe) the encoding is set to the default encoding (ASCII in python2.) try `print sys.stdout.encoding` in both time (when you run your script as the terminal as stdout and when you redirect to a file) and you will see the difference.

Try also this in your command line:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding;'
UTF8
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding;' | cat
None
```

More Info can be found [HERE](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails):

Comment: Use the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING if you want to control then encoding of the pipe.

Comment: **Programs should not behave differently when run over a pipe.**  This is a yet another stupid Unicode-related bug where Python curls over backwards to appease burgeoning pods of hysterical porpoises. It should be fixed.

Comment: @tchrist: This issue was solved in python3, where the default encoding is no more ASCII.