# python unicode handling differences between print and sys.stdout.write

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, stdout

I'll start by saying that I've already seen this post: [Strange python print behavior with unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013354/strange-python-print-behavior-with-unicode), but the  solution offered there (using PYTHONIOENCODING) didn't work for me.

Here's my issue:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr  9 2010, 11:16:46)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
>>> a = u'\xa6'
>>> print a 
Â¦
```

works just fine, however:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

throws an error.  The post I linked to at the top suggests that this is because the default console encoding is 'ascii'.  However, in my case it's not:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

So any thoughts on what's at work here and how to fix this issue?

Thanks
D.

Comment: On python 2.7 with utf-8 terminal encoding, everything seems to be working. Can you try sys.stdout.write(a.encode("UTF-8")) and try to see what happens?

Comment: Yep, that worked... Oops, I just realized that I used wrong Python version to generate the sample.  I should've used 2.6.5.  So why is this happening?  A bug in pre 2.7 Python?

Comment: Appearantly, when trying to write to stdout, yout Python tries to encode your unicode object with ascii, but fails miserably. I am not sure why, but mine doesn't do that :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to a long-standing bug that was [fixed](http://hg.python.org/lookup/r84621) in python-2.7, but too late to be back-ported to python-2.6.

The documentation states that when unicode strings are written to a file, they should be converted to byte strings using [file.encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.encoding). But this was not being honoured by sys.stdout, which instead was using the default unicode encoding. This is usually set to "ascii" by the [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) module, but it can be changed with [sys.setdefaultencoding](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding):

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Aug 14 2011, 12:32:40) [GCC 4.6.2] on linux3
>>> a = u'\xa6\n'
>>> sys.stdout.write(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec cant encode character u'\xa6' ...
>>> reload(sys).setdefaultencoding('utf8')
>>> sys.stdout.write(a)
¦
```

However, a better solution might be to replace [sys.stdout](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) with a wrapper:

```
class StdOut(object):
    def write(self, string):
        if isinstance(string, unicode):
            string = string.encode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
        sys.__stdout__.write(string)

>>> sys.stdout = StdOut()
>>> sys.stdout.write(a)
¦
```

Comment: stdout has many different functions (close, flush, ...). It would be better here to replace the write function only